# Rails: simple update_attributes not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, update-attributes

I have a "rota" model with an attribute "turn_index". For some reason, update_attributes does not seem to be working. Any clue why?

```
  rota = Rota.create
  rota.turn_index.should == 0 -- passes
  rota.update_attributes(:turn_index=>1)
  rota.turn_index.should == 1 -- fails
```

The schema for rota is:

```
  create_table "rotas", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "turn_index"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end
```

Rota Model:

```
class Rota < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rotazations
  has_many :users, :through => :rotazations
  has_many :invitations

  before_save :set_turn_index

  private

  def set_turn_index
    self.turn_index = 0
  end
end
```

Comment: what does the Rota Model look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `before_save`, you're setting `turn_index` to 0. You can fix this by only setting it on create:

```
before_save :set_turn_index, on: :create
```

Or set the default value on `turn_index` to 0 in your migration.

Answer (score 0):

Your `before_save` is always setting `turn_index` to 0

Comment: oh damn, cant believe it was that.